# How to point Tomcat 7 server.xml docbase residing in Amazon ec-2 instance to a folder in Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

In my local I am successfully able to point my docBase like this - `<Context docBase="D:/XYZ" path="/video" />`.

Since my Java based application is going to be hosted on AWS, I am using Amazon ec2 to deploy my application and Amazon S3 to host the videos, thumbnails and profile photos of the users. So I changed my tomcat 7 server.xml entry on ec2 to `<Context docBase="http://MyS3EndPointURL" path="/videos" />`

However when I am trying to restart my tomcat, it errors out saying -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/MyS3EndPointURL/Videos does not exist or is not a readable directory
```

I tried removing `http://` but as I expected it didn't work as well.

I understand that I will have to give permission to Tomcat to have access to these folders, however I have these questions -

1. How do I provide this access ?
2. When a user uploads a video will my application have the write access to these folders ? If no, how to provide that ?

From whatever reference articles are available on AWS, none talks about this issue. Stackoverflow question searches are mostly outdated information or people are suggesting to have another static domain. I am supposed to release the product this weekend in BETA mode but I am stuck because of this issue. Any pointers, suggestions would just save me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your setup, your app is hosted on Tomcat, you want your users to upload content to S3, so you can refer to your assets via an S3 http endpoint.

If so, your app server configuration is incorrect. Your server will not serve any videos itself; that job is offloaded to S3. Rather than define a docBase as you have, you will want to provide a URL rewrite rule so that http://www.example.com/videos/ point s to the new S3 http endpoint EG  http://assets-example-com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/videos/.

> When a user uploads a video will my application have the write access to these folders ? If no, how to provide that.

If you have not already, you need to develop an upload interface with the appropriate permissions the the above bucket.  See [Java Upload File](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html) for more information

Comment: Thanks for the info Rodrigo. Let me make these changes and see if it works. I will accept the answer then.. once again thank you very much for pointing me in right direction.

Comment: I have never used url rewrite. So couple of stupid questions - 1) Since I am using tomcat 7, from whatever I read on internet looks like I need to use http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ for rewriting the url. 2) So when the browser asks for a file let's say : http://example.com/videos/MyS3Bucket/VideosFolder/testvideo.mp4 it will redirect to http://assets-example-com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/MyS3Bucket/VideosFolder/testvideo.mp4 but the browser address will still remain at example.com only right ? so that user will be able to watch the video at example.com. Sorry for a naive question

Comment: Yes that is correct. For quick validation of this approach, simply use the S3 endpoint http://assets-example-com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/videos/ for now in your HTML.  When upload and permissions are all working to your satisfaction, then you can implent the rewrite last.